# JTable insert column instead of rows

Tags: java, swing, insert, jtable

Is it possible for a `JTable` to have static rows and dynamically inserted columns (i.e. instead of inserting rows, to insert columns), as presented below?

```
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(String[], String[][]);

  String rows[] = {"row1","row2"};
  String columns[][] = {{"A","100"},{"B","200"},{"C","300"}};
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows,columns);
  JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, update your `TableModel` and `fireTableStructureChanged()`. Naturally, editing your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would help.